# Best practice for securing Node api using Azure Active Directory

Tags: angular, azure, azure-active-directory, mean-stack

I am building a mean stack application.For authentication , i plannned to use azure Active directory based on the below example  [1]:https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/WebApp-OpenIDConnect-NodeJS  i am able to generate JWT token in my nodejs api, then what is the best practise to pass the token from nodeapi to angular application.
(If i pass JWT token in URL params,it will be exposed.)

Also there is an alternative approach to generate JWT token from angular using "microsoft-adal-angular6" module.

Which is the best approach to generate JWT token (either from UI or from api end )?

Comment: Could you clarify what you intend to do with the JWT token? Are you looking for access tokens (i.e. to call an API)? Or an ID token (i.e. to identify the signed-in user)?

Comment: ID token to check wheather the user is verified